# SQL Server Join two queries

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a table (t) that I need to get some information from.
I´m using this 2 queries to get it.
But is there a way to make it in single query ?

```
SELECT nrplu, SUM(preco) as TP, SUM(kg) as TK, seccao 
FROM t 
GROUP BY nrplu, seccao


SELECT nrplu, count(*) as TT FROM t GROUP BY nrplu
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
 WITH CTE_preselect AS
 (SELECT nrplu, count(*) as TT 
 FROM t 
 GROUP BY nrplu)

 SELECT t.nrplu,TT, SUM(preco) as TP, SUM(kg) as TK, seccao 
 FROM t
    JOIN CTE_preselect ON t.nrplu = CTE_preselect.nrplu 
 GROUP BY t.nrplu,TT, seccao
```

Comment: I get the error "'CTE_preselect' is not a recognized GROUP BY option."

Comment: Change `From t JOIN t` to `From t JOIN CTE_preselect`